# UMTS/HSDPA Data SIM Card on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wwan

Hardware is a Compaq Mini Notebook with HP HS2300 Broadband Wireless Module. UMTS provider and SIM card is Vodafone. Wireless WWAN is working well under Windows XP, but um my second System, UBUNTU 14.04 only WLAN has functionality.
Does anybody know a software connecting the existing hardware to UBUNTU 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers`

I have gut feeling your module will be there and it will need to download additional drivers. (best doing of this is when you have some alternative connection available)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a 6930p, un2400 WWAN card and Ubuntu 12.04. Both the 2300 and the 2400 have the same issue – on startup, the driver needs to load the firmware into the card. Being a proprietary binary blob, the firmware cannot be shipped with Linux – one needs to download the Windows driver installation package from HP and extract the firmware from it. With this hack it is reportedly possible to get the card to work under Linux.

Another approach might be to install a different, more Linux-friendly PCI-e WWAN adapter. Unfortunately I do not have any reliable reports of PCI-e models that are known to work. I have been able to use a Huawei USB adapter as well as an Option Express Card adapter, both of which were recognized out of the box, thus PCI-e adapters from these vendors might work too. I have also used an Ericsson F5521gw PCI-e adapter with a different laptop, which is supported out of the box but has a bug (most likely in the firmware) that causes it to lock up and refuse to reconnect until the next reboot.

I ended up working around the HP WWAN issue by using the USB stick, and on the other machine I live with the Ericsson bug.